# Clang and LLVM rebuild after linux libraries update, every time

Tags: c++, gcc, fedora, llvm-clang

I am using Fedora 30 with GCC 9.1 and I have built Clang 6.0 & LLVM from files using the **ninja** build system.

To create my own tools using libtooling libs, I put them under

```
LLVM/tools/clang/tools/extra/my_project ....
```

The problem I am facing is that every time I update my fedora 30 libs, i.e.,

```
sudo dnf update
```

something happens to clang (maybe because of system libs update).
When I run the **ninja** command from llvm build directory after system update, it starts 
to rebuild Clang and LLVM libs from scratch. I have to sit for 2hrs to 3 hrs
every time after my system update.

Is there any workaround to this problem? Or any way to not let this happen?

One solution is not to update my fedora.